# Using DateTimeOffset with DateTimeKind.Unspecified in c#

Tags: c#, .net-core

There are some instances where I need to store a date as DateTimeKind.Unspecified.  This is due to business rules where if a date and time is specified we want to store as utc, but if a date only is specified we want to know it’s unspecified and therefore not do any client conversion.  This works well.

Using DateTimeOffset would have some good benefits for global users but I cannot see any obvious way to use DateTimeKind.Unspecified with DateTimeOffset.    Is this possible or is DateTime actually better for my use?

Comment: With a DTO, the DT “rules” are applied up-front. There is no good Date-only (eg. TZ-independent) core type. There is also arguments for storing a DateTime + TZ (which could be NULL) discretely. This (no offset/no TZ) can’t be accounted for   in a DTO directly. We have custom DT+TZ type pairs in some code, and there are some good C# time libraries too.